# Charge required to lift a piece of paper

Tags: electrostatics, charge, polarization

Say I rubbed a plastic ruler on my hair just enough to lift exactly one hole-punch size piece of paper, to get the paper to stick to the rod. Roughly what is the net charge on the rod, in Coulombs?

This question is intended to gauge the magnitude of the Coulomb in relation to a hands-on effect.

Answer (score 0):

Relevant forces are the electric force, $F=EQ$, and the force of gravity at sea level, $F = mg$.

There are two Coulomb forces, one pushing towards the rod, one pushing away from the rod. The paper is a dipole with a positive charge on one end and a negative charge on the other end. Your rod is probably negatively charged after contact with hair, so the positive side attracts and the negative side repels.

Approximate the charged rod as a line charge distribution with charge density $\lambda = Q_{rod}/L$ where L is the length of the rod. Further approximate the rod as being infinitely long, so that you can use the symmetry to obtain the electric field of the rod as a function of radius from the center of the rod

$E(r) \approx k_e\lambda/r$, where $k_e$ is the Coulomb constant.

which can be derived from Gauss's law starting with the above approximations.

First solve the system:

$E(r_1)Q_{+} = E(r_2)Q_{+}$

$Q_{+} + Q_{-} = 0$

to obtain $Q_+$ and $Q_-$ in terms of $r_1, r_2, Q_{rod}$

Now balance forces:

Let the coulomb force of the rod on $Q_+$ be $F_+$

Let the coulomb force of the rod on $Q_-$ be $F_-$

Let the force of gravity on the paper be $F_g$

$F_+ + F_- + F_g =0 $

Solve for $Q_{rod}$ in terms of $r_1, r_2$

Approximate $r_1$ is the distance from the center of mass of the rod to the closest point on the paper. Approximate $r_2=r_1+D$ where D is the width of the piece of paper.

Plug in and solve.

Comment: Thanks, but I did ask for a value. It would be interesting to see the variation in the final results derived by different models and approximations.

Comment: You're welcome. There's just some simple algebra and a few measurements between you and your first estimate. Me just giving you a value is not possible without measurements of your apparatus unavailable to me. Moreover, it is not interesting to me, not likely to be useful to anyone searching the SE in the future, and, more importantly, off topic for this SE.

Comment: OK, maybe I should rephrase the question. I do not have a specific apparatus, but am curious as to what a typical value of charge would be for some small electrostatic effect you can see. Thats why I didn't provide measurements. The value was intended to be useful to anyone with the same curiosity. For example - the charge dissipated in a lightning strike could vary greatly depending on the conditions, but a simple figure like ~10 Coulombs is still useful.

Comment: Nanocoulombs, plus or minus a few orders of magnitude. A coulomb is very large unit when discussing static charge. One coulomb acting on one coulomb at one meter has about the same force as a billion kilogram weight.